# Getting mobile device hardware information via javascript

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, browser

via Javascript you can get a lot of information about your hardware and other components about your system, like shown [here](http://browserspy.dk/)

With mobile devices you are not getting that much information. I'n not asking how to find out the mobile device name, that's easy, or even the udid. I want to know, if I can access some device characteristics, like some sort of installed plugins used by the browser, or new developments on this topic.

On [this site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.battery?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.navigator.mozBattery) I discovered, that I can access the battery status, Or with `window.navigator.mozVibrate([200]);` I can activate the vibrate function. So far both work only on firefox mobile (android).

An interesting information would be about the built in camera, something like how much megapixel does it have, or does it have a flash light? Or what kind of cpu (single-, dual-, or quad-core) is built in?

To sum it up: what hardware information can I get about a mobile device (iOS/Android/Windows Phone) via javascript?

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get a limited set of information about the device by using PhoneGap i.e. placing the PhoneGap script on your server and checking the appropriate values if the device is mobile. Check this link: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device

Comment: Thanks for our answer. I looked into Phonegap, but as far as I understand it, PhoneGap is used to create mobile apps. So I have to create an android project and create an actual app (like *1), that's not what I want. I want to get that information via javascript, over a regular website. | *1: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android